# Query nested documents mongodb with python pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, nested, pymongo

My data look like this:

```
{'_id': ObjectId('6068da8878fa2e568c42c7f1'),
 'first': datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 24, 14, 5),
 'last': datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 24, 15, 5),
 'maxid13': 12.5,
 'minid13': 7.5,
 'nsamples': 13,
 'samples': [{'c14': 'C',
              'id1': 3758.0,
              'id10': 0.0,
              'id11': 274.0,
              'id12': 0.0,
              'id13': 7.5,
              'id15': 0.0,
              'id16': 73.0,
              'id17': 0.0,
              'id18': 0.342,
              'id19': 6.3,
              'id20': 1206.0,
              'id21': 0.0,
              'id22': 0.87,
              'id23': 0.0,
              'id6': 2.0,
              'id7': -79.09,
              'id8': 35.97,
              'id9': 5.8,
              'timestamp1': datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 24, 14, 5),
              'timestamp2': datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 24, 9, 5)},
             {'c14': 'C',
              'id1': 3758.0,
              'id10': 0.0,
              'id11': 288.0,
              'id12': 0.0,
              'id13': 8.4,
              'id15': 0.0,
              'id16': 71.0,
              'id17': 0.0,
              'id18': 0.342,
              'id19': 6.3,
              'id20': 1207.0,
              'id21': 0.0,
              'id22': 0.69,
              'id23': 0.0,
              'id6': 2.0,
              'id7': -79.09,
              'id8': 35.97,
              'id9': 6.2,
              'timestamp1': datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 24, 14, 10),
              'timestamp2': datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 24, 9, 10)},
               .
               .
               .
               .
```

Can someone help on how to find for example the `id13` when `timestamp1` is equals to
 `datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 24, 14, 5)`
`Samples` is an `array`.
This is what i have wrote.

```
cursor = mydb1.mongodbbucket.aggregate(
          [
              {
                "$match": {
                   "samples.timestamp1": {"$eq": datetime.strptime("2018-01-24 14:10:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")}
                }
              },

              {
                  "$project": {

                      "samples.id13": 1
                  }
              },
            ]
        )   )
```

The ideal output would be `id13`:7.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the right answer from @dheemanthbhat:

```
cursor = mydb1.mongodbbucket.aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$samples" },
    {
        "$match": {
            "samples.id13": { "$exists": true },
            "samples.timestamp1": { "$eq": datetime.strptime("2018-01-24 14:10:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") }
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "samples.id13": 1
        }
    }
])
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```py
cursor = mydb1.mongodbbucket.aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$samples" },
    {
        "$match": {
            "samples.timestamp1": { "$eq": datetime.strptime("2018-01-24 14:10:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") }
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "samples.id13": 1
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: Code is in JavaScript. You might have to convert it to Python.

Comment: Thank you for you help!I appreciate it!I did what you said to me but it doesn't seems to work

Comment: What is the output? Are you getting any error?

Comment: i get something like this {'_id': ObjectId('6068a09578fa2e568c35bb6a'), 'samples': None} a multiple times

Comment: Yes its the same as before unfortunately

Comment: I understood the problem some of your documents does not have `id13` element in `samples` array. Check the updated JavaScript code in terminal and give feedback. Thanks!

Comment: do you want to contine to chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230731/discussion-between-xaroulis-gekas-and-dheemanth-bhat).